# Error CS1615 Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword in SetProperty method C# DevExpress

Tags: c#, mvvm, devexpress

I'm trying to create a property called `SelectedTreeViewItem` but I'm getting this error :

> Error CS1615  Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword

Note: the BindableBase is a class a from `DevExpress.Mvvm` ,

**This is the signature of the `SetProperty` method:**

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, Expression<Func<T>> expression, Action changedCallback)
{
    return SetProperty(ref storage, value, GetPropertyName(expression), changedCallback);
}
```

How can I fix this error?

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _selectedTreeViewItem = null;
        public string SelectedTreeViewItem
        {
            get { return _selectedTreeViewItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTreeViewItem, value); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the signature of SetProperty?

Comment: Sorry , I forget to mention that this property is from Devexpress , please check again my post , I've updated it

Comment: In c# class objects are always passed By REF (not By Value).  REF is required on both the calling statement and in the procedure parameters.  The error indicates you only have REF in one place instead of both places.

Comment: But the signature doesn't match. You pass in two arguments while the signature requires four.

Comment: @jdweng That's not true. objects are always passed by value. that's why modifying the parameter reference does not modify the argument. Otherwise `ref` had no special meaning.

Comment: @jdweng "By value" means the memory location's value i.e. the object is passed. "By reference" means the reference to the memory location is passed.

Comment: According to devexpress documentation , I think that the correct use will be like this :  `public string SelectedTreeViewItem
        {
            get { return _selectedTreeViewItem; }
            set { SetProperty(() => _selectedTreeViewItem, value); }
        }`   https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17350/mvvm-framework/viewmodels/bindablebase

Comment: We are talking about this [BindableBase](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17350/mvvm-framework/viewmodels/bindablebase#bindable-properties-1)? Then its seems the behavior of that method changed between Net Framewok and Net Core and you are mixing that up. Only look at the help the mentions Net 4.

Comment: They are using the same documentation for the two frameworks

Comment: @BionicCode. : Class objects are absolutely passed BY REF.  If you add an item to a list inside a method the new item will be recognized by the parent method.  No REF is required.

Comment: @jdweng This is because you are still modifying the same *value*, which is in this case the list. Without `ref` you have two independent references: one caller reference (variable) and a local reference (method parameter). Initially both references point to the same value (the List). Now, if the method overwrites the local reference like `listParameter = new List()` then you are assigning a new value to the *local* reference. The caller's argument wont be affected by this change. The caller's reference still points to the old List .

Comment: @jdweng Time to hit the school bench: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters

Comment: @BionicCode. Can you take that to a private discussion? It does not have anything to do with the  question at hand.

Comment: @BionicCode :  Your link is for a VALUE which is not a CLASS object.  A list is a CLASS object so you do not need REF.

Comment: @jdweng Read the link, please. Don't mixup value types and reference types with object references. A value type still has an object reference (a pointer that points to the object's memory location. Value types are always copied: a new memory location is created - caller and operation operate on two independent memory locations/objects. Opposed to reference types where the memory location is shared - caller and operation operate on the same memory location/object. Then there is the object reference also known as variable, which points to the memory location of a value type or reference type.

Comment: @jdweng *"Your link is for a VALUE which is not a CLASS object. A list is a CLASS object so you do not need REF"* - The link is about passing references. It explains how passing a reference to a value type and reference type differ - and of course what passing a reference actually means.

Comment: @jdweng Let's stop this please. You have the link where Microsoft explains their concept of type references and value/reference types. You have google too. You obviously have trouble to understand the differences. Maybe you should learn how programming languages manage memory to understand the difference between a memory reference and a memory location. The type reference is passed by value or by reference. The memory location the type reference points to is either a value type or a reference type. The memory location is the value of a type reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DevExpress documentation [BindableBase](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17350/mvvm-framework/viewmodels/bindablebase) :

> **Using Properties With Backing Fields**
>
> An application performance can decrease when a property is frequently updated (due to the calculation of property names from lambda expressions and storing property values in the Dictionary). To accommodate these scenarios, use storage variables for properties and calculate property names once from the static constructor using the BindableBase.GetPropertyName method.

```cs
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    static string Property1Name;
    static ViewModel() {
        Property1Name = BindableBase.GetPropertyName(() => new ViewModel().Property1);
    }

    string property1;
    public string Property1 {
        get { return property1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref property1, value, Property1Name); }
    }
}
```

You need to pass the property name in the third parameter like :

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _selectedTreeViewItem = null;
    public string SelectedTreeViewItem
    {
        get { return _selectedTreeViewItem; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTreeViewItem, value, nameof(SelectedTreeViewItem)); }
    }
}
```